# PyQt5 - "Cannot set X11 selection owner" error when using .setMimeData() on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python, qt5, ubuntu-16.04, pyqt5, pyautogui

Keep Getting this error when using PyQt5's `clipboard.setMimeData()`

`QXcbClipboard::setMimeData: Cannot set X11 selection owner`

```
def copy(index, app):
    clipboard = app.clipboard()
    Mode = clipboard.Clipboard

    initialMimeData = clipboard.mimeData(mode = Mode)

    import pyautogui
    pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'c')

    mimeData = clipboard.mimeData(mode = Mode)
    clipboards[index-1]["Data"] = mimeData
    clipboard.setMimeData(initialMimeData, mode = Mode) #getting the error here
```

I'm running this on Ubuntu 16.04. Why do I get this issue and how do I fix it?

Comment: Seems like a more general issue than implied here. No need for python to experience this.  I don't use python at all and seeing this error in `konsole` when trying to select text with mouse.

Comment: @arielf Also I experienced it in a python-free konsole session. Konsole won't inject the selection into the clipboard, I don't know, why.

Comment: Did you already try adding a timeout?